# Existence of box counting dimension.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fractals

Let $F\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be non-empty and bounded.

We say that a countable family of set $\{$ $U_i$ $\}$ is a $\delta-cover$ for $F$ if $F\subseteq \bigcup_{I\in I}U_i$. Let $N_{\delta}(F)$ $=$ 
$min \{$ # of sets in any $\delta-cover$ of $F$ $\}$. Where $U_i$ has diameter at most $\delta$ (And greater than 0)

Then consider the unit interval $F=[0,1]$. For $0<\delta<1$, we get:

$\frac{1}{\delta} \leq N_{\delta}([0,1])<1+\frac{1}{\delta}$

My questions are:

(1) How do you prove the above inequalities?

(2) Why does $N_\delta(F)$ exist?

Comment: What is $\delta$ doing in the definition of $\delta$-covers?  Do you require something like each $U_i$ has diameter at most $\delta$ or something?  At the moment, it looks like $N_\delta(F)=1$ for any $F$.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. I removed that part by accident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Let $N=N_{\delta}([0, 1])$. If $N < \frac{1}{\delta}$ then there must be a $\delta -cover$ $\{U_i\}_{i=1}^N$ of $[0, 1]$. But since $[0, 1] \subset \cup U_i$, we have $1 \le \sum \delta = N\delta < 1$, absurd.

(2) Note that, since $F$ is bounded, the closure $\overline{F}$ of $F$ is bounded, so it is also compact. Now, the collection $ \{ B(x; \frac{\delta}{2}) \}_{x \in \overline{F} }$ is a $\delta -cover$ of $\overline{F}$, so it must have a finite subcover. Therefore $N_{\delta}(F)$ exists.

Comment: Does it always exist? Not just for the unit interval, I mean.

Comment: Yes, because $F$ has compact closure.

Comment: May you please elaborate on why having a compact closure means that it always exists?

Comment: Moreover, with regards to (2), nowhere did I mention that the collection of subsets are open.

Comment: You also didn't say otherwise, so I can work with any cover I please.

Comment: Thanks for choosing my answer even though I couldn't help with the second part of the inequality.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll just have to think about it some more. The concept of totally bounded is foreign to me so I suppose I need to read up on that.

Comment: For the right inequality, let $n=\lceil 1/\delta\rceil$.  Pick $U_i=\left[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}n\right]$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$.  Then $\{U_1,U_2,\ldots,U_n\}$ is a $\delta$-cover of $[0,1]$.